# purpose of prod certs at Azure IoT Edge Device when not setting the edge device as gateway

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge

I am following the steps to have prod certs at IoT Edge Device using doc "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-manage-device-certificates?view=iotedge-2020-11" and in my use case I am not setting up Edge device as the gateway. So in this case the tls connection will be between what and for what purpose these certs will be consumed ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Microsoft docs:

> These verifications enable a TLS (transport layer security) secure
> connection between the runtime, the modules, and the IoT devices.

In your case, you're not securing the connection with other IoT devices. The certificates are still used to secure the connection between the runtime and the modules. You can find more information about this certificate and the way it's used [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/iot-edge-certs?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034&view=iotedge-2020-11)

Comment: how can we ensure/check that the certs used by the runtime are the ones which we are specifying?

Comment: I'm not sure how to check if you're device is not set up as a gateway. You could temporarily allow connections on 8883 and use the command mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/iot-edge-certs?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034&view=iotedge-2020-11#example-of-iot-edge-certificate-hierarchy)